# Encoding issue pg_dump [PostgreSQL]

Tags: windows, postgresql, dump, pg-dump

I have to migrate a DB from one server to another. Both server are using PostgreSQL 9.6.24.

I'm using the pg_dump tool to dump my DB in plain sql , with this command :

`pg_dump -h myHost -p myPort -U myUser  -o myDb > dump.sql`

I'm restoring the dump on the other server with :

`Get-content dump.sql | psql -h myHost -p myPort -U myUser myDb`

But every special characters, like french accents "é" "ï" etc ... , are replaced by question mark :
[Old DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWZFr.png)
[Restored DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeZmI.png)

The two DB are both in UTF8 encoding

I tried to force the encoding when dumping with the `--encoding=UTF8` parameter but i still could'nt make it work.

Is there any encoding setting i'm missing out ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes i am

Comment: Both servers are on linux but  i'm accessing those remote servers and saving the dump on my local windows computer

Comment: `?` appears only when Unicode text is read or displayed using a single-byte codepage. Are you using PowerShell Core or the old Windows PowerShell? While Windows is natively Unicode, in the past console applications would use the user's codepage as the default encoding. In PowerShell Core (released in 2017) and the newer Console infrastructure, UTF8 is always the default

Comment: If you use Windows PowerShell then a) seriously consider upgrading to PowerShell Core or b) use ` Get-content -Encoding UTF8`

Comment: Which Windows version are you using? Windows 10 is the oldest supported Windows version and comes with PowerShell *Core*.

Comment: Try without redirecting: `psql ... -f dump.sql` and `psql ... -f dump.sql`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks you for your detailed explanation, i tried using powershell 7.1 and i got my characters replaced by unicode like "├®" instead of the question mark.

However i did make it work by calling the pg_dumb and the restore through my remote server on Ubuntu. But i'm still looking for solution to fix this encoding issue on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running `pg_dump` from WSL/Ubuntu instead of powershell

---

`sudo apt install postgresql` to install `pg_dump` in WSL

But if you need the latest `pg_dump` version follow these instructions instead https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/